# I am getting an error when i tried to seed my database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Am getting an error when i try to seed my database in laravel 5.4 using faker

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use app\PostModell;    
class postcarseeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {

            // Let's truncate our existing records to start from scratch.
            PostModell::truncate();

            $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

            // And now, let's create a few articles in our database:
            for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
                PostModell::create([
                    'title' => $faker->sentence,
                    'body' => $faker->paragraph,
                ]);
              }
        }
```

Above is my seeder class which am calling in my DatabaseSeeder.php with the following command `$this->call(postcarseeder::class);` so that i can run `php artisan db:seed`

The error am getting is
[image]

[image]

Comment: When you seed, you also need watering ^.^ hurr durr

Answer (score 4):

You should use full namespace:

```
App\PostModell
```

Or add this to the top of the seeder class:

```
use App\PostModell;
```

Comment: am using the full namespace

Comment: @DENNISKITHINJI you're using `app` and not `App`. If `App` doesn't work, please show the model class' namespace.

Comment: Thanks its now seeding